# Select from DynamoDB with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is my table on AWS DynamoDB

```
Table name: records
Primary partition key:  member_id (Number)
Primary sort key:   datetime (String)
```

I wanna select 10 results from table by member id, datetime and range. From 1 to 10, 10 to 20.

All I done is to get 10 entries from database. So how can I select by member id, datetime and range?

```
Ex. where member_id = 3000 and datetime between Time.now and Time.now + (2*7*24*60*60)
```

My code:

```
table = @@dynamo_db.tables['records'] 
table.hash_key = [:member_id, :number]
table.range_key = [:datetime, :string]

table.items.select(:limit => 10).collect do |item_data|
  return item_data.attributes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my question

```
@@dynamo_db = AWS::DynamoDB.new(LOCAL_SETTINGS["aws_dynamo"]) # needed for local testing
table = @@dynamo_db.tables['records'] # table name should be @@dyamo_table but I used records for local test
table.hash_key = [:member_id, :number]
table.range_key = [:datetime, :string]

table.items.where(:member_id).equals(member_id).collect do |item_data|
  item_data.attributes
end
```